# Question, regarding modeling as a process

Tags: modeling, workflow

I've been using blender to do small projects as a hobby, and i have one question, which i haven't been able to find around the internet, so i figured it's a good decision to ask here.

I've seen many videos of people modeling firearms, cars and other models, with a lot of detail. I've noticed, that they have their own ways of modeling and that's fine, but i've seen 1 thing that i can't really figure out. People, making a singular model out of multiple meshes, which are just intersecting, or perfectly aligned. But then, i've seen people model from 1 mesh by extruding, making loop cuts and using various add-on features to make a model out of 1 single mesh.

My question is: Is modeling out of multiple meshes good and perfectly functional for all needs, CGI, 3D printing, games and animation ? Or is modeling from 1 mesh the "better" option, or is there even a golden rule about how you should make your model ?

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Comment: *"perfectly functional for all needs, CGI, 3D printing, games and animation"* there isn't golden rule suitable for each purpose. Each one of them requires different options. Printing needs actual and precise geometry. Game model is required to be lightweight so lowpoly, intersections don't matter until it's not visible.

Comment: So, intersecting different meshes to form 1 model is perfectly fine, if i want to make a game asset as long as it's low poly and the intersections aren't visible, i shouldn't worry about compromising the functionality of the model ?